# CruiseControlException "log.xml does not exist" help

Tags: java, logging, ant, cruisecontrol

I have a project that have cruiseControl running to build our things.

In my config.main I have a `<onsuccess>` with a `<antpublisher>`

**But when some error occur in the ANT I'm receiving a exception:**

```
exception publishing results with net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.publishers.OnSuccessPublisher for project usforce net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.CruiseControlException: ant logfile /home/usforce/cruisecontrol-bin-2.7.3/log.xml does not exist.
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.builders.AntBuilder.getAntLogAsElement(AntBuilder.java:424)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.builders.AntBuilder.build(AntBuilder.java:213)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.publishers.AntPublisher.publish(AntPublisher.java:86)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.publishers.ConditionalPublisher.publish(ConditionalPublisher.java:61)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.publish(Project.java:750)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.build(Project.java:264)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.execute(Project.java:149)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectConfig.execute(ProjectConfig.java:405)
            at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectWrapper.run(ProjectWrapper.java:69)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I really dont have this log.xml... And I don'k know how this file should be, a log4j? Commons?

I google it and could not found what this file for..

Well any tips could help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar problem here? http://markmail.org/message/xujmrnq4ht2tlsgy

Comment: josek, I found that this error is only happening when something wrong happens with my antpublisher. When all works fine this file is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the log CruiseControl is complaining about is the build log file. Typically the name of the file is something like `log20100213101358Lbuild.1.xml` and the file is not placed in the CCDIR, but within logs dir,  e.g. `${CCDIR}/logs/${project.name}`.

It sounds like a bug in CruiseControl. Maybe you could try to reproduce the problem and file an issue in their issue tracker?